# Qt QSqlDatabase and QSqlTableModel compatibility with PostgreSQL view?

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, qsqltablemodel

I have encountered a problem using QSqlTableModel on PostgreSQL view. Let me show the relevance code here first.

a view is created with the following code running on PostgreSQL 9.2.4:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW reporters_spaces_edit AS 
 SELECT reporters.name AS reporter_name, spaces.name AS space_name, 
    reporters_spaces.reporter_id IS NOT NULL AND reporters_spaces.space_id IS NOT NULL AS linked
   FROM reporters
  CROSS JOIN spaces
   LEFT JOIN reporters_spaces ON reporters.id = reporters_spaces.reporter_id AND reporters_spaces.space_id = spaces.id;
```

My C++ code compiled on VC2005 with Qt 4.4.0 looks like this:

```
void populateModel()
{
    QTableView lrView;
    QSqlDatabase lrDb(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL"));
    ...
    QSqlTableModel lrModel(lrDb);
    lrModel.setTable("reporters_spaces_edit");
    if (!lrModel.select())
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(
            0,
            tr("Database Error"),
            lrModel.lastError().text());
        return;
    }
    lrView.setModel(lrModle);
}
```

It shows "Unable to find table reporters_spaces_edit" on the message box.

I tried to find out all the views in the database. I added the following line:

```
QPlainTextEdit lrEdit;
lrEdit->setPlainText(lrDb.table(QSql::Views).join("\n"));
```

The resulting list is the same as

```
QPlainTextEdit lrEdit;
lrEdit->setPlainText(lrDb.table(QSql::Tables).join("\n"));
```

Does it mean SQL view is not supported on QSqlTableModel when running on PostgreSQL?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It may well be a bug. You're using an awfully old version of Qt. Update to 4.8.5 and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The production environment is stuck with this old version. :(
I would really like to try on newer version as well.

Comment: @crackpot What does that matter? Test with a new version, if it fixes the problem then look for the commit that fixed it and backport...